# jquery app works only in FF3.5, IE8 throws errors and Chrome3 locks up!

Tags: jquery, firefox, internet-explorer-8, google-chrome

Has anybody else experienced this? I get tons of JS errors surrounding the jquery markup, such as the following line of code, works in FF but generates an error "Object doesn't support this property or method" in IE.

```
$("input[type=text]").css("border","1px solid grey");
```

Chrome doesn't give me the same error, but it locks up when I perform my autocomplete. The autocomplete works perfectly in FF.

This is very strange to me. I don't even know where to begin debugging this!

If anybody cares to see what I'm talking about, I'll provide my url.

```
  $("#med").autocomplete("ajax-getAllMeds.php", {
            selectFirst: false,
            autoFill: true,
            max: 20,
            minchars: 2,
            cache: 30
  });
```

edit: I removed the autocomplete functionality. When you click on one of the meds at the top of the page, the text loads fine in FF but not at all in IE and Chrome.

Comment: A simple page with one input and the line of code you listed works just fine on IE8 and Chrome. Care to share more of the page?

Comment: Still need more code.  There's not enough to figure it out.  Perhaps you should make the url available.

Comment: check out http://bit.ly/ljcJO

Comment: In Firefox 3.0.14 on X64-64 Linux, I do not see any text when clicking on the various drugs. I also do not see any text when clicking on the drugs in the alpha version of Chrome on Linux. The two pages look identical, save the boxes go to the right of the screen on Chrome, and to the left under Firefox. Konqueror behaves like Chrome.

Comment: yeah, that is what is happening in IE8 and Chrome, no text when clicking on the various drugs. I'm not sure why it isn't in those browsers when it does display correctly in FF3.5 on Windows Vista and XP.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like jQuery isn't loading up in IE8.  You don't happen to have any IE-specific conditional logic in your mark up do you?   I'd need more code to make heads or tails out of the issues with Chrome.

Comment: it seems to be around my autocomplete logic:
  $("#med").autocomplete("ajax-getAllMeds.php", {
   selectFirst: false,
   autoFill: true,
   max: 20,
   minchars: 2,
   cache: 30
 });

Comment: oh, and no, no IE conditional logic in there

Comment: I don't suppose you could add the code the question.  Sort of hard to read in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you trying to split the CSS into the several border properties as I think most browsers don't directly map multi-component properties into their respective components when CSS is being set through the DOM properties in JavaScript.

My suggestion:

```
$("input[type=text]").css({
  "border-size": "1px",
  "border-style": "solid",
  "border-color": "grey"});
```